# Multiple comparison violating the assumption of homoscedasticity

Tags: statistics, anova

I have had some trouble analysing my data with one-way ANOVA. While the Levene's Test showed that the data violated the assumption of homoscedasticity, I tried to use Tamhane's T2 Test to correct the results when conducting multiple comparison (there is significant differences among three levels). However, when I looked into results of different pairwise comparisons, I found that some pairs had unequal SD while the other did not.

Concretely speaking, for example, the IV has three levels (A1, A2, A3) and the levene's test showed that the three levels have unequal SD. However, such results may occur when A1-A2 has unequal SD but A2-A3 and A1-A3 have equal SD. In this case, should I correct all pairwise comparisons given that the levene's test showed that the whole data violated the assumption of homoscedasticity? or should I only correct the comparisons with unequal SD (e.g., A1-A2) but not correct the others with equal SD (e.g., A2-A3) when reporting the results in the paper?

Looking forward to your answers! Thanks!

In my opinion, given that some correction techniques (e.g., Tamhane's T2 Test) provided results without examining whether all pairwise comparisons have unequal SD, I tend to favor that correcting all comparisons may be reasonable. However, because I did not find any guidance or discussion about this case, I hope to get some suggestions from others.